# Make a optional Dialog depending on a Custom Action Result with WIX toolset

Tags: conditional-statements, dialog, wix, windows-installer

I created a custom Action in WIX that sets a global Value in the session depending on the machine State.

> session["INSTALLTOKENREQUEST"] = "1";

The custom Action is run, the value is set, as confirmed by the msi installer log derived with:

> NameOfMy.msi /l*v c:\location\location\msilog.txt

resulting in

> MSI (s) (50!64) [09:20:28:921]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding
> INSTALLTOKENREQUEST property. Its value is '1'.

I tried several permutations of using this to open a dialog. First was existence check. I did not declare this property and went with a simple existence check.

```
<InstallUISequence>     
<Show Dialog="InputDlg" After="ExecuteAction">      
INSTALLTOKENREQUEST</Show> 
</InstallUISequence>
```

The dialog in question did not open up, even though the value was set. It does pop up, when forced with a direct value like 1.

I then declared the property properly, thinking it might be a visibility issue.

```
<Product Id="*" etc...
...
<Property Id="INSTALLTOKENREQUEST" Value="0"/>
```

comparing it for value with:

```
<InstallUISequence>
        <Show Dialog="InputDlg" After="ExecuteAction">
            INSTALLTOKENREQUEST = "1"
        </Show>
    </InstallUISequence>
```

I then set the default value of the property manually to "1". Which opened the dialog, confirming the boolean logic at least works.

According to

https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix/blob/537e79d3c8b99e1576db48b19c8071c0922342f2/src/dtf/WixToolset.Dtf.WindowsInstaller/CustomActionProxy.cs#L21C52-L21C65

a sessionHandle is handed down to the dll. This seems to be a copy instantiated here:
https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix/blob/537e79d3c8b99e1576db48b19c8071c0922342f2/src/dtf/WixToolset.Dtf.WindowsInstaller/CustomActionProxy.cs#L63

The session is after the action is executed then copied into the arguments
https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix/blob/537e79d3c8b99e1576db48b19c8071c0922342f2/src/dtf/WixToolset.Dtf.WindowsInstaller/CustomActionProxy.cs#L131 and a ActionResult derived (Success, Failure, etc.) but no changed Propertys are taken along for the ride.

Thus i conclude that session["PropertyName"] is a one way data field from the parent-process.

My question is, how do i get the session["NameOfProperty] = value  - i set to propagate back from myCustomActions.dll - or is this approach wrong entirely? The Log seems to be entirely missleading in this regard, as even the end states (S) log confirms a changed value.

Should i send inter process message from the custom Action instead? How does WIX incooperate messages from "external" dlls like the ones that are custom actions?

In addition:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/obtaining-context-information-for-deferred-execution-custom-actions?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Seems to suggest there is a workaround for this, but the answers given is  unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

In MSI, only the first dialog is in the sequence.  The rest of the dialogs are considered interior dialogs and are authored into the wizard loop using control events (Publish in WiX). To do an conditional dialog requires control events with mutually exclusive conditonal expressions.

Welcome

Next  OptionalDialog   INSTALLTOKENREQUEST

Next  NormalDialog Not INSTALLTOKENREQUEST

OptionalDialog

Back  Welcome

Next NormalDialog

NormalDialog

Back OptionalDialog INSTALLTOKENREQUEST

Back Welcome Not INSTALLTOKENREQUEST

Comment: But the  INSTALLTOKENREQUEST set in a CustomAction remains always the same value for the optional dialog?

Comment: Is this optional dialog supposed to be a blocker  Like you have to fix something to proceeeD?